# Java 9: run legacy jar

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I have a jar built before Java 9. I'm trying to run a class that is in that jar using Java 9.

From all I read about automatic modules, this should work:

```
java -p lib/Legacy-1.3.0.jar -m Legacy/com.blah.MyClass
```

But instead I get this:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.blah.MyClass in module module Legacy
Caused by: module Legacy: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Yes, com.blah.MyClass is in Legacy. Can I run a class from an automatic module? Why is the word `module` repeated twice in that error message above?

If I run `java --list-modules -p lib/Legacy-1.3.0.jar` I see:

```
Legacy@1.3.0 file://path/to/jar/Legacy-1.3.0.jar automatic
```

If I run `jdeps --generate-module-info . lib/Legacy-1.3.0.jar`, I get:

```
module Legacy {
    requires java.logging;

    requires transitive java.activation;
    requires transitive java.xml;
    requires transitive java.xml.bind;
    requires transitive java.xml.ws;

    exports com.blah;
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to just run it, or do you specifically want to try and run it as a module? Would it be good enough to just use the 'old' way of running things, so using `java -cp lib/Legacy-1.3.0.jar com.blah.MyClass`?

Comment: Aside: Can you also add to the question if you are able to generate the module-info using `jdeps --generate-module-info . Legacy-1.3.0.jar` and/or what is the result of `jar --describe-module --file=lib/Legacy-1.3.0.jar`?

Comment: The reason I'm not doing it the old way is because the legacy jar has dependencies and it is nice to have them automatically pulled in using the new module based way of doing things.

Comment: Add `jdeps` to answer.

Comment: Does following these steps work: 1. Creating module `jar --create --file=lib/Legacy-1.3.0.jar \
        --main-class=com.blah.MyClass -C mods/Legacy` 2. Then executing it using `java -p lib -m Legacy` ?

Comment: @naman - no, gets `Error parsing file arguments`.

Comment: You asked "Can I run a class from an automatic module? Why is the word module repeated twice in that error message above?". Yes it should work although it is a very unusual way to run an application when you don't have any explicit modules on the module path. Also the "module module" error message has fixed in JDK 13 via JDK-8221368.

Comment: Just on the NoClassDefFoundError, it might be that there is another error that is hidden. Does `java -cp lib/Legacy-1.3.0.jar com.blah.MyClass` work? I'm curious if it reveals other errors.